# php barcode - display multiple barcode in single page

Tags: php, while-loop, barcode

I created a php page that print the barcode. Just to view it before i print it on an A4. Still in testing phase. The codes are as below.

```
<?php
include('include/conn.php');
include('include/Barcode39.php'); 
$sql="select * from barcode where b_status = 'NOT-PRINTED'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);

$i=0;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$acc_no = $row["b_acc_no_code"];
$bc = new Barcode39($row["b_acc_no_code"]);
echo $bc->draw();
$bc->draw($acc_no.$i.".jpg");
echo '<br /><br />';
$i++;
}
?>
```

Without the while loop, it can be printed, but only one barcode. How to make it generate, for example in the database have 5 values, it will print 5 barcode in the same page. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another bar code source. Because It is generate only one bar code per page. Can't able to create multiple bar code per page.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but comes up in searches so is probably worth replying to.

I have successfully used the Barcode39 to display multiple barcodes. The trick is to get base64 data from the class and then display the barcodes in separate HTML  tags.

The quickest way to do this is to add a $base64 parameter to the draw() method:

```
   public function draw($filename = null, $base64 = false) {
```

Then, near the end of the draw() method, modify to buffer the imagegif() call and return the output in base64:

```
// check if writing image
if ($filename) {
    imagegif($img, $filename);
} 
// NEW: Return base 64 for the barcode image
else if ($base64) {
    ob_start();
    imagegif($img);
    $image_data = ob_get_clean();

    imagedestroy($img);
    return base64_encode($image_data);
} 
// display image
else {
    header("Content-type: image/gif");
    imagegif($img);
}
```

Finally, to display multiples from the calling procedure, construct the image HTML in the loop and display:

```
// assuming everything else has been set up, end with this...
$base64 = $barcode->draw('', true);     // Note the second param is set for base64
$html = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $numBarcodes; $i++) {
    $html .= '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.$base64.'">';
}
die('<html><body>' . $html . '</body></html>');
```

I hope this helps anyone else facing this challenge.